# How to list all directories which doesn't contain a given file?

Tags: powershell

I want to list all the subfolders of \MYNAS\Profiles\pc which doesn't contain a file named "pålogging.txt". I managed to list all the subfolders which actually do contain this file, with this oneliner:

```
ls . -r -filter "pålogging.txt" | %[$_.DirectoryName} | Get-Unique
```

Now i want to do the exact opposite to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | 
Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and -not (Test-Path "$($_.FullName)\pålogging.txt" -PathType Leaf) }
```

Comment: Allmost! But this will also list all the subfolders of the subfolders which doesn't contain this file. Btw, can I have this sorted on the "LastWriteTime" field?

Comment: You want to list just one level of sub-folders? Pipe to sort-object To sort by LastWriteTime

Comment: Yes, only one level of subfolders.

Comment: For one level only remove the Recurse parameter